# NSClassFromString stopped working after upgrading to XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When attempting to create a class with the following code

```
id obj = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

i'm now getting nil as the result.

This issue appeared when I upgraded to XCode 6.

Previously this code worked on all iOS platforms (iPhone 6 not previously tested of course). No code modifications have been made.

The issue appears on the iPhone 5s and any newer models, regardless of iOS version (tested with iPhone 5s physical device, and iPhone 5s and iPhone6 Simulators, running iOS v7.03, v7.06, v7.1, and v8.0)

It does not occur on iPhone5 or earlier (tested on iPad 3 physical hardware, and iPhone 5 and, iPhone4s simulators and also running iOS v7.03, v7.06, v7.1, and v8.0)

ie:

- if testing on an iPhone5 or earlier, it will work.
- if testing on an iPhone5s or later it will not.

Other Notes:

- The class that we are trying to load is a custom plugin class that we
  have created. (We are using the plugin system from cocos2dx v3).
- The class is defined in a child project.
- We DO have the -ObjC linker flag set in the project settings.

I'm getting the same behaviour using the following code:

```
id obj = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed: className];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this.

I've seen some mention of NSClassFromString possibly requiring the module name prefixed to the class name (eg: using  @"ModuleName.ClassName"), however I haven't been able to get any combinations/variations of this working.

Comment: its suspicious that all the devices it doesnt work on are 64bit... but could be coincidence

Comment: Did you added arm64 as platform?  also verify  if (NSClassFromString(className)) is valid

Comment: Yeah, we have arm64/armv7 as our architectures.  Also, the NSClassFromString(className) call returns a nil (ie: without the alloc+init)